# Xamarin app crashing because of missing constructor in FormsEditText

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Our xamarin app crashes sometimes with the following exceptions:

System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsEditText from native handle 0xffce196c (key_handle 0xf8c2ea1).

System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsEditText::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership).

Sadly this bug was not reproducible and only happens in production.

There is also a bug on github for this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13956.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround in our app looks like this.

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override FormsEditText CreateNativeControl()
    {
        return new CustomFormsEditText(Context);
    }
}

public class CustomFormsEditText : FormsEditText
{
    public CustomFormsEditText(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public CustomFormsEditText(System.IntPtr i, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership j) : base(Forms.Context)
    {
    }
}
```